# WinDbg symbol load issue

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

I am using WinDbg to load a crash dump from managed code (C#, a console application built for *Any CPU*). I am debugging on a x64 platform. I have put the related [PDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) file into the symbol path.

But when I use the `lm` command to see load models, the symbol of the console EXE file application can not be loaded. I have tried to execute `.reload /f`, but I still cannot load the symbol for my application.

BTW: I have the full source code for my application. My application is built for [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 3.0, but the machine I am working on to debug is installed with lastest .NET 3.5 + SP1. Could the mismatch be the issue?

How do I analyze this problem further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, I would try using [`!sym noisy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565396.aspx) and then reloading the module. You should see information for the module that it is trying to load. If you have a local cache, a common status you may see is `E_PDB_CORRUPT`. First delete the symbol file from the local cache and then use `.reload /f`.

If it can't find the symbol, ensure you have the proper symbol packages available or [Use the Microsoft Symbol Server to obtain debug symbol files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503).

Comment: If I need to display line number information of .cs file (when executing command like clrstack), do I need to set up source file path or not? My confusion is I am confused whether Windbg is capable to extract line number information from managed code (EXE/DLL) or related PDB file?

Comment: Thanks Kris, your reply gives me a lot of help. I have followed your advice but has a new issue, appreciated if you could take a look. My new issue is posted here,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552927/symbol-issue-when-debugging-c-code